# Trying to get javascript change html style printed by php

Tags: javascript, php, html, onchange

I have written a JavaScript function, which changes value of a `range` slider `onchange/ oninput`. However, when I want the function to change the values `height` and `width` of a `<div>`, which has been printed by PHP, it doesnt change it. Should'nt it work since the HTML is already prited ?

HTML looks like this:

```
<input id="imageSize" type="range" name="rangeInput" min="80" max="300" onchange="updateInput(this.value)." oninput="updateInput(this.value)" >                                                       
    <p id="valueInput"></p><p id="procent">%</p>
```

JavaScript looks like this:

```
function updateInput(val) {
  document.getElementById('valueInput').innerHTML = val;
  document.getElementById('oneResult').style.width = val;
  document.getElementById('oneResult').style.height = val;
}
```

PHP looks like this:

```
print '<div id="oneResult" style="background-image:url(Pictures/'.$img.'); height: 100px; width:100px; ">
        <a id="word'. $x .'">'. $textConversion[$x] .'</a></div>';
```

Is it just some syntax error or am I missing something ? Or is it just not possible ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on console ?

Comment: Well no, it just doesnt change the html code. But I know the function is working, bacause I am printing out the value in the `<p>` tag dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the unit:

```js
function updateInput(val) {
  document.getElementById('valueInput').innerHTML = val;
  document.getElementById('oneResult').style.width = val + 'px';
  document.getElementById('oneResult').style.height = val + 'px';
}
```

```html
<input id="imageSize" type="range" min="80" max="300" onchange="updateInput(this.value)" oninput="updateInput(this.value)">
<p id="valueInput"></p>

<div id="oneResult" style="background: red; height: 100px; width:100px; "></div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is there also a way to get it working on all my `<div id="oneResult">` tags ? Because I have a PHP loop which generates multiple tags and the JS functions only works on one for some reason.

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate the `id` attribute within the document. If you want to have more such elements, you should assign different ids to them.

Comment: Or could I change them to `class` elements instead and use `getElementsByClassName` ? would that work ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it like this. Then you will have to iterate through the array of these elements and do what you want do to with them.

Comment: I have updated my JS like you can see above, but I am not sure how to structure the `for` loop, any recommendation ?

Comment: You can do it like: `document.getElementsByClassName('some-class-name').forEach(function (element) { element.style.width = val + 'px'; } )`. Don't modify the original question. Don't make a mess.

Comment: Yeah I was going to back-edit it, no worries. Ok let me try it, thanks!

Comment: soo something like this: `document.getElementsByClassName('oneResult').forEach(function    changeWidth(element) { element.style.width = val + 'px'; } );` ?